# Unable to patch `\hyper@normalise` command with `\patchcmd`

Tags: etoolbox

Is it possible to add a hook to `\hyper@normalise` command  without overwriting all the macro. I wish to add a hook at the end of macro just before `\hyper@n@rmalise` that I could add custom definitions to normalize.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
\begingroup
  \endlinechar=-1 %
  \catcode`\^^A=14 %
  \catcode`\^^M\active
  \catcode`\%\active
  \catcode`\#\active
  \catcode`\_\active
  \catcode`\$\active
  \catcode`\&\active
  \gdef\hyper@normalise{^^A
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\^^M\active
    \def^^M{ }^^A
    \catcode`\%\active
    \let%\@percentchar
    \let\%\@percentchar
    \catcode`\#\active
    \def#{\hyper@hash}^^A
    \def\#{\hyper@hash}^^A
    \@makeother\&^^A
    \edef&{\string&}^^A
    \edef\&{\string&}^^A
    \edef\textunderscore{\string_}^^A
    \let\_\textunderscore
    \catcode`\_\active
    \let_\textunderscore
    \let~\hyper@tilde
    \let\~\hyper@tilde
    \let\textasciitilde\hyper@tilde
    \let\\\@backslashchar
    \edef${\string$}^^A
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
    \csname hyper@normalise@hook\endcsname % <--HERE
    \hyper@n@rmalise
  }^^A
\endgroup
```

But I want to do it with `\patchcmd` that I don't need to frozen the `\hyper@normalise` in my package. In this macro a lot of catcodes are changed so it gives an error:

```
Runaway definition?
\active \def  \catcode `\
! File ended while scanning definition of \etb@resrvda.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\hyper@normalise{\hyper@n@rmalise}{\csname hyper@normalise@hook\endcsname \hyper@n@rmalise}{}{}
\show\hyper@normalise
\makeatother

\begin{document}
aa
\end{document}
```

Comment: well you can't patch it because it does lots of catcode magic. And you *should* not patch it, as it is an internal hyperref command. If something is missing make a feature request.

Comment: Asked for this hook long time ago https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/36 ;)

Comment: yes and rereading that you didn't give a convincing reason and the issue was therefore closed.